# Can't get Gulp to work on Git Bash

Tags: git, bash, gulp

So I'm new in all this git ambient, I've been trying to learn JavaScript and as part of the course/book I'm following I have to use Git and Gulp, but I've been having trouble getting the local Gulp to work:

```
$ gulp
module.js:442
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\Git\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:440:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:388:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:575:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:352:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:144:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:467:3
```

[image: Screen Capture of the output]

I've installed gulp global with no problem and since it works (almost) perfectly on the Developer Command Prompt for VS2015 it might be related directly to git Bash. I've searched the internet for a solution with no success, although there might be similar problems related to some updates but no clear solution and as I'm a beginner, everything seems kind of complex at this point...

Thank you all for your help!!

Comment: Did you check to see if the file is actually located in `C:\Program Files\Git\node_modules\gulp\bin\`? I don't think visual studio uses that path.

Comment: I did and it was not there, when I moved it, it worked... But I is it a normal behavior, I mean if I'm running a local dependency that was installed in my root folder, why would be git looking for it in its program dir?

Comment: That's not normal, but part of the problem with using Windows. There's lots of nonsense hoops you have to jump through to get Linux utilities to work on Windows. You installed gulp globally in your home directory, but git bash's home directory is actually a directory within your home directory. I ran Windows for a long time and have been much happier since I switched to Linux.

Comment: I know I really really like Linux, but it lacks the design tools I need to use... That's why I'm stuck with windows and a dual-boot doesn't seem that efficient to me. 
Anyway that's just what I thought was happening, any ideas on how to "re-set" the git bash's home dir?

Comment: I feel your pain because I actually work in a mixed environment so I have to tread both sides. I run a Windows vm inside my Linux desktop, so you might consider that too. Resetting the home directory might be possible, but I don't know.